# How to print the value of number during a "x" number of loops?

Tags: python, while-loop

basically, Im trying to use a while loop to make an arithmetic sequence of numbers the code i made being rather simple:

```
x=2
while True:
    x=x+3
    print(x)
```

but a problem with this code of course is that there is no way i can find the value of x during a certain number of loops and rather this code prints every possible value in the sequence.

Does anyone know how i can make the code in a way that i can choose to print the value of x after a certain number of loops?

Comment: Replace your `while True` loop with a `for i in range(n)` loop?

Comment: Basically this code is output = loopNumber * 3 + StartPoint. !

Comment: Conditions. You should print the value if the value has certain criteria. Such as: if it is divisible by, let's say 10. for that you can use `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest for a known nuber of iterations is a for-loop:

```
x = 2
iterations = 5

for _ in range(iterations):
    x = x + 3

print(x)
```

This of course can be shortened in this particular example:

```
x = x + 3 * iterations
```

Comment: Huh? never thought of using a for loop thank you!